# Iterating over MongoDB cursor is slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to iterate over a full MongoDb collection with ~2 million documents. Therefore I am using the cursor feature and the `eachAsync` function. However I noticed that it's pretty slow (it takes more than 40 minutes). I tried different batchSizes up to 5000 (which would be just 400 queries against MongoDB).

The application doesn't take much CPU (0.2% - 1%), nor does it take much RAM or IOPs. So apparently my code can be optimized to speed up this process.

**The code:**

```
  const playerProfileCursor = PlayerProfile.find({}, { tag: 1 }).cursor({ batchSize: 5000 })
  const p2 = new Promise<Array<string>>((resolve, reject) => {
    const playerTags:Array<string> = []
    playerProfileCursor.eachAsync((playerProfile) => {
      playerTags.push(playerProfile.tag)
    }).then(() => {
      resolve(playerTags)
    }).catch((err) => {
      reject(err)
    })
  })
```

When I set a breakpoint inside of the eachAsync function body it will immediately hit. So there is nothing stuck, it's just so slow. Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: Have you tried to profile your app? e.g. with https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/V8-Profiler ?

Comment: @AlexBlex Well I get 97.8% "Unaccounted" and I have no idea what that's supposed to be. See here: https://i.imgur.com/wV9i8cL.png

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Get all `tag`s from all documents in `PlayerProfile`?

Comment: @Styx Yes exactly, I need all `tag`s from two different collection and find the union of these tag arrays.

Comment: So you need to get only unique tags from each collections, right?

Comment: @Styx Yes kinda, it's a bit more complex as the second collection stores the `tag` in a nested object array. I don't get what you are driving at, as my main problem is the slow iterating cursor / eachAsync function.

Comment: Well, it seems as [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. There is a better way to get unique values of particular fields of documents, rather than iterate cursor over all of them.

Comment: It's simplified for stackoverflow, I need to iterate over the whole collection for other jobs too. Collecting a number from 2 million documents shouldn't take 30 minutes or so.

Comment: Well, perhaps you should update your answer then? Because "simplify" by using the most ineffective way to iterate and asking to improve it — seems like wasting of time and efforts.

Comment: @Styx no that's not needed, I already tried the options and I am sure that I need to iterate on all documents. And even if I wouldn't need to iterate the question why it's so slow remains. I put a bounty on it to figure THIS out as I need it a lot. I am not looking for alternative ways as I did this already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That feature was added in version 4.12 (most up to date atm) and isn't really documented yet.

`eachAsync` runs with a concurrency of 1 by default, but you can change it in the parameter 'parallel'. ([as seen here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/1504d64c2e0465cefd100a541ddc9209605145a8/lib/services/cursor/eachAsync.js#L26))

Thus your code could look something like this:

```
const playerProfileCursor = PlayerProfile.find({}, { tag: 1 }).cursor({ batchSize: 5000 })
const p2 = new Promise<Array<string>>((resolve, reject) => {
const playerTags:Array<string> = []
playerProfileCursor.eachAsync((playerProfile) => {
  playerTags.push(playerProfile.tag)
}, { parallel: 50 }).then(() => {
  resolve(playerTags)
}).catch((err) => {
  reject(err)
})
})
```

Comment: That actually did the trick, that was well hidden I guess :D. It's MUCH faster now and now the CPU usage is also higher (as expected)