# Getting 300k data from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to get 300k data with NodeJS from the database and pass it to the client(HTML side) for reporting and virtual scroll. I started with MySQL and it was taking around 14 seconds (2 tables joined). Since I'd like to speed up, I changed it to MongoDB but it takes around 31.2 seconds in one collection without any joining with the native MongoDB npm package.

NodeJS MongoDB source code

```
  const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
  .
  .
  .
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  const collection = db.collection('test');
  const startTime = performance.now()

  const findResult = await collection.find({}).toArray();
  const endTime = performance.now();
  console.log(`Time elapsed: ${endTime - startTime} milliseconds`);  
  console.log('Found documents 1st element =>', findResult[0]);
```

I'd assume MongoDB was going to take less time versus MySql but I guess there is something wrong with my code (I also tried fastify-mongodb, fast-json-stringify, streaming but none of them could not speed up ). What do you suggest? Because I researched lots of papers and most of the people gets +3m data around 10seconds and I know MongoDB is a good choice for big data even my data is not big enough :)

Comment: I suggest you have a look at [indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answers but its not related with index because data is the same for testing so index will not work

Comment: @Koodies An index will not help, because he loads **all** data from the collection. However, the response to your comment is also pointless.

Comment: Do you really need all data from the collection? How does the SQL statement look like? Does the MongoDB/MySQL runs on the same host as your node.js?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes they all run on the same host, yes I need all data to be able to create a report(current is sample data)but what I don't understand is how can MongoDB be slower than MySQL. Where do I make a mistake :(

Comment: Have you profiled the operation?  How long did it take for the request to reach the server? How many batches were returned? How long did node.js take to deserialize each batch?  If you want to speed it up, first determine where it is slow.

Comment: Opps you guys are right my bad. Misread.

Comment: Returning everything in one request is bad. You should implement something like  "pagination" where you can skip entrys and just return amount of x datasets. 300k is a huge amount, not to mention how long it will take to render everything...

Answer (score 0):

In general mongoDB is good in multiple small single document reads based on indexes(already in memory) , this is coming from the fact that the data is allocated on storage in random 32k compressed blocks and it is not written sequentially , so in case you read the full collection there will be multiple IOPS operations to your storage that turns out to be the bottleneck for sequential reads in your case. If you immediately  try to read the same collection second time you will find that the read is much more faster since the documents are already cached in memory and OS fs cache. To improve this performance for bigger volumes you may shard the collection and distribute the data in multiple shards so it use less IOPS per individual shard when fetching the full collection. Btw by 300k data you mean 300k documents or total size of collection is 300k bytes since 31 seconds is huge amount of time , maybe documents are relatively big in this 300k collection or you have some infrastructure issue?
(300000 x 16)/(1024*1024) = ~ 4,5TB max  , how big is your collection?
FileSystem? Storage ?

Testing in my machine it seems there is no issue in mongo but in the stages after you fetch the data:

```
 db.collection.find({}).explain("executionStats")
    "executionStats" : {
    "nReturned" : 300000,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 174,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 300000
```

Some interesting results:

```
  mongos> var a=new Date().getTime();var doc=db.collection.find({});var b=new Date().getTime();var doc2=doc.toArray();var c=new Date().getTime();printjson(doc2);d=new Date().getTime();var ba=b-a,cb=c-b,dc=d-c;print("find:"+ba+"ms  toArray:"+cb+"ms  printjson(doc2):"+dc+"ms");
```

doc=find({}):             0ms

doc2=doc.toArray():    3296ms

printjson(doc2):      67122ms

Something that you may try:

1. Increase the cursor [batch size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/) :
   var doc=db.collection.find({}).batchSize(3000000)
   ( In my tests higher batch sizes provided 2-3 times better execution times )
2. Use eachAsync paralelized , check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671321/iterating-over-mongodb-cursor-is-slow)
   ( havent check that , but you may try )

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Here is my schema and here is my sample collection I have 300k times this document. And it's not the full collection just some of them because the data can be larger.
 "name": String,
  "surname": String,
  "email": String,
  "schoolId": ObjectId,
  "dob": String,
  "gender": String,
  "nickname": String,
  "address": Object,
  "language": String,
  "schoolName": String,
  "phoneDetail": Array,
  "createdAt": Number,
  "updatedAt": Number
The average size of the document is 778 bytes and the total is around  27MB

Comment: What are your server characteristics, RAM, CPU , wiredTigerCacheGB ? Sharded cluster or replicaSet?

Comment: Here is my server info: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10900K CPU @ 3.70GHz, CPU(s):              20, Core(s) per socket:  10,Thread(s) per core:  2  but it uses 30gb ram 6 cpu, because other resources used by other applications

Comment: 32 sec for 27MB  data is really huge amount of time , there must be some issue ...

Comment: did some testing in my laptop with similar collection size and doc , same thing touk me 4 sec

Comment: i7 8xcore , 16GB RAM , 500GB SATA SSD  , mongo/d/s 4.4.12